# how to normalize discrete probability distribution $P_n = \binom{N + n - 1}{n} p^N (1 - p)^n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

How do I normalize this distribution?

$P_n = \binom{N + n - 1}{n} p^N (1-p)^n$

I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^n = \frac{1}{1-(1-p)}$.

Also I know that $\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \binom{N + n - 1}{n - 1} p^N = \frac{1}{(1-p)^n}$

And I know that eventually the cumulative result of $P_n$ must be $1$.

But I don't know how to handle the $\binom{N + n - 1}{n} p^N$.

Furthermore, how would I calculate the expected value of this distribution?

Comment: what is the domain? $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N}_0$ or some finite set?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention, it is $n \in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $N \in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Incidentally, this distribution is called a [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution). (Here you have $\mathrm{NB}(N,1-p)$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#cite_note-ctcs-3), the distribution is already normalized:

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}\binom{N+n-1}{n}p^N(1-p)^n=p^N\frac{1}{(1-(1-p))^N}=1$$

I also checked it with a script:

```
N = 20
M = int(1e+04) 
p = 0.67

Pn = 0
for n in range(0,M):
    Pn += scipy.special.comb(N+n-1,n)*p**N*(1-p)**n
    
print(Pn)
```

---

Also the expected value is

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=N\frac{1-p}{p}$$

Indeed, we can compute
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n P_n
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \binom{N+n-1}{n}p^N(1-p)^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) \binom{N+n}{n+1}p^N(1-p)^{n+1} \\
&= \frac{1-p}{p}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) \binom{N+n}{n+1}p^{N+1}(1-p)^{n} \\
&= \frac{1-p}{p}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) \frac{(N+n)!}{(n+1)!(N-1)!}p^{N+1}(1-p)^{n} \\
&= N\frac{1-p}{p}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(N+n)!}{n!N!}p^{N+1}(1-p)^{n} \\
&= N\frac{1-p}{p}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{(N+1)+n-1}{n}p^{N+1}(1-p)^{n} \\
&= N\frac{1-p}{p}\cdot 1
\end{align*}$$
since the last series is $1$, by the above argument (it is the original sum of probabilities, but with $N+1$ as parameter instead of $N$).

Comment: Is there a particular trick to get the $\mathbb{E}[X]$?

Comment: I only have computational evidence for now

Comment: @Snoop If you are interested, I can add the proof here (as a comment, or to your answer).

Comment: @ClementC. that's cool! Post it however you want

Comment: @Snoop Added. ${}{}$

Comment: @ClementC. Very clever